# Android JobScheduler - can't create a persistent job

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-jobscheduler

I am trying out the new JoScheduler API that has come with Android Lollipop. I have so far managed to successfully create and have a job run with a delay of 6000 milliseconds with no network requirements without an issue.

However, I have just tried to persist the same job via using the setPersisted(true) function. As soon as the job build() function is called it now fails saying that I need the RECEIVED_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in the Manifest file.

But I have added the permission:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.android" >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I have even added the following code before the job is added to see if the app has the permission registered:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
int hasPerm = pm.checkPermission(Permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, 
context.getPackageName());
if (hasPerm == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
   // Goes into here every time
}
```

However, when the job is built I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: requested job be persisted without holding RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.
```

My code to create and add the job to the JobSchedular:

```
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyJobService.class);
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, serviceComponent)
        .setMinimumLatency(6000)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPersisted(true);
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

My JobService manifest declaration:

```
<service
        android:name=".service.MyJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

So I am wondering if I am doing something else wrong that anyone can spot. The only thing i'll note incase it does make a difference is that the code is run in an IntentService so I am wondering if this might be a reason why the JobScheduler can't find the permission.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue, but then realized that I hadn't **re-installed** my app after adding the boot permission. So the app never got an opportunity to request the required permission when it was installed.

Once I uninstall and re-installed the app it works.

Note: My understanding is that Apps need to get their permission at install time. However I stand to be corrected here.

Answer (score 21):

Just as **43matthew** said, It's probably caused by JobScheduler cache.

It's solved after device reboot.

PS: Make sure you have the following permission in your XML.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: As noted by @RajiithAttapattu you need to reinstall the app

Comment: Reboot solved the issue for me. No need to reinstall the app.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the JobScheduler keeps a cache of uids that hold this permission:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerService.java#736

Perhaps you added the permission, but the phone didn't restart and therefore the JobScheduler has not updated its cache?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I think your issue is that you are starting an intent service. You need to add the BIND_JOB permission to your intent service as well.

```
    <service
        android:name=".your.intent.service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

We use the JobScheduler to schedule a job and we do have the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.

We started to get this error after updating Google Mobile Ads?? to:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0

Reverting back to 21.4.0 fixed the issue for us.

**Edit:**

[This solution](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/khqkEUc3nWU/m/j4OAt-IOAQAJ) worked for us. Add **tools:node="merge"** to the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" tools:node="merge"/>
```

Note that Rajith's answer still needs to be taken into account. You need to uninstall and re-install the app.

Answer (score -4):

I noticed that if job scheduler is set to persist then you may fall into this error, remove

```
setPersist(true);
```

from scheduler